# Unrolling line in d3js Linechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made a line chart in d3js. The implementation is give below.
However, the chart appears abruptly in the screen(without transition).
How can I make the chart appear in the screen with a transition such that the chart gives an "unrolling effect" i.e. as if the line is being drawn as the user is watching over a period of "t" seconds.

[This is what I have in mind.](http://blog.visual.ly/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/transitions.html#13)

```js
var lineData = [
  [new Date('Mon Aug 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'), 100],
  [new Date('Tue Aug 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'), 100],
  [new Date('Thu Aug 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'), 66.66666666666667],
  [new Date('Fri Aug 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'), 50],
  [new Date('Sat Aug 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'), 40]
];

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 30
};
var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([lineData[0][0], lineData[lineData.length - 1][0]]).range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, height]);

var svgContainer = d3.select("#lc-visual").select("svg").attr("width", margin.right + width + margin.left).attr("height", margin.bottom + height + margin.top);

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line().x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return height - yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .interpolate("linear");

var svgGroup = svgContainer.append('g');

var lineGraph = svgGroup.append("path")
  .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", '#000')
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="group">
    <!-- </form> -->
    <div id="lc-visual">
      <svg id="#line-svg">
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Has my response answered your question? If so, please indicate so by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to accomplish this.

1. Interpolate the `d` attribute between points. This allows you to have better control over each line segment.
2. Interpolate `stroke-dashoffset` to have the appearance of
   *drawing* the line. This provides a better, more fluid visual experience

[This codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/live/LpbpLb) demonstrates the difference between the two methods.

#### Method 1: Using the `d` attribute

The first method will add each line and point in sequence, giving you options for providing transitions that involve the points themselves.

You want to first pass in the first point of your data to the `d` attribute like so: `selection.attr('d', lineData[0])`. Then you call your transition and pass in the `lineData` using [`attrTween`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#attrTween) and declare a tween function: `selection.attrTween('d', tween)`.

**Your code would look like this:**

```
var lineGraph = svgGroup.append("path")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000) // must pass in duration for tween function
  .attrTween('d', tween) // call tween function with attrTween

function tween() {
  var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
      .domain([0,1]) // where 0 is start of tween and 1 is end of tween
      .range(d3.range(1, lineData.length + 1)); // return current point and all previous points in data
  return function(t) {
    // render the line in sequence from beginning
    return lineFunction(lineData.slice(0, interpolate(t)));
  };
}
```

As you can see, this will transition the rendering at *each* point, but will not simulate the drawing of the line.

#### Method 2: Using `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` attributes

If you aren't familiar with these attributes, you might want to read about how `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` operate on paths. Here is a good [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) about how they work and here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/xbNJaZ) that I created that is demonstrative of how these attributes work (set all values to their maximum, then slowly decrease `stroke-dashoffset`).

The gist of this method is that we want to set your initial values like this:

```
selection
  .attr('stroke-dasharray', lineLength + ' ' + lineLength)
  .attr('stroke-dashoffset', lineLength);
```

You want your path selection's attributes at the *end* of the tween to be like this:

```
selection
  .attr('stroke-dashoffset', 0);
```

You are transitioning the `stroke-dashoffset` from the length of the path to 0. Here is how you would accomplish that in your case.

**Your code would look like this:**

```
// render path so it's possible to check its length
lineGraph
  .attr('d', lineFunction(lineData));

// get total length of path
var lineLength = lineGraph.node().getTotalLength();

lineGraph
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attr('stroke-dasharray', lineLength + ' ' + lineLength)
  // here we transition the stroke-dashoffset to simulate 'drawing' the line
  .attrTween('stroke-dashoffset', tween);


function tween() {
  // get values between lineLength and 0
  var interpolate = d3.interpolate(lineLength, 0);
  return function(t) {
    return interpolate(t);
  };
}
```

I've created a [working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbyzEZ) to demonstrate both of these methods using your example. I've commented out the second example to better demonstrate the procedural advantages of the first and the visual advantages of using the second.